# Destroy all session variables without invalidating session java

Tags: java, session, httpsession

I am attempting to remove all my session attributes without invalidating the session since I need some session variables like this:

```
    session.setAttribute("fatal", "fatal error");
    session.setAttribute("sgadded", "Added");
    session.setAttribute("sgverified", "Something");
    session.setAttribute("sgmodified", false);
    session.setAttribute("glexists", false);
    session.setAttribute("fatal", false);
    session.setAttribute("gladded", false);
    Enumeration em = session.getAttributeNames();
    while(em.hasMoreElements()){
        if((String)em.nextElement() != "uname"){
            session.removeAttribute((String)em.nextElement());
        }
    }
```

But I am getting an error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:925)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:956)
    at java.util.Collections$2.nextElement(Collections.java:3665)
```

Is there a better way of removing all the session variables at once without invalidating the session. I do not want to call `session.invalidate()` at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few weird things going on in this code.

- First off, you call `em.nextElement()` twice in the while loop, and that second call to `em.nextElement()` doesn't ensure that there is actually another element there.
- Second, when doing string comparisons in Java you shouldn't use `==` or `!=`, those operators check for reference equality, what you want is value equality so you need to use the `.equals` method. In your case, `!"uname".equals((String)em.nextElement())`. And as a quick note, notice how we used the string literal first in this string equality. This is the preferred way to do it in Java so that if the `em.nextElement()` happened to be null, this code won't throw a nasty `NullPointerException` (because the .equals method checks for null, and if the argument is null, it returns false)

Thus your code would end up looking something like:

```
while (em.hasMoreElements()) {
    String element = (String)em.nextElement();
    if (!"uname".equals(element))
        session.removeAttribute(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you got this message. You check if the enumeration has at least one element, then you fetchs and compares one element and remove another one. On top of that "==" compares references, not values. At least your loop body should looks like

```
String temp=(String)em.nextElement();
if (!temp.equals("uname")) {
    session.removeAttribute(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works too

```
Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames())
                .stream()
                .filter(s -> !s.equals("uname"))
                .forEach(session::removeAttribute);
```